# Quiero tratar de tratar un error como valido

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Estoy desarrollando un programa que en una tabla me muestre datos según el tipo de usuario que inicie sesión, y lo he logrado, aunque algo chapucero ya que pienso actualizar mas adelante el código, el caso es que esa tabla funciona con ajax y JQUery que envía los datos a un archivo php, el problema es que cuando no devuelve nada en la consulta me sale un error que es este

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<br />
<b>"... is not valid JSON
```

lo cual a lo largo del desarrollo del programa me he dado cuenta de que esto se debe a que el php convierte  el resultado en JSON y al estar vacio, al tratar de leerlo en js me lo da por malo, y eso quiero que haga, pero a parte de eso quiero que cuando salga ese error me cambie a una imagen, no se si me he explicado bien.

Este es el código del script

```
function sacarDatos() {
            let usuario = "<?php echo $_SESSION['nombre'];?>";
            switch (usuario) {
                case "Bianca Albert":
                $.ajax({
                    url: '../controllers/listarLicitaciones.php?nombre=Bianca Albert',
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function(response) {
                        if (response != null) {
                        let respuestas = JSON.parse(response)
                            console.log(respuestas);
                            let template = '';
                            respuestas.forEach(respuesta => {
                            template += `<tr id="${respuesta.id}">
                            <td>${respuesta.nombre}</td><td>${respuesta.ofertante}</td>
                            <td>${respuesta.estado}</td><td>${respuesta.ejecutor}</td>
                            <td>${respuesta.limite}</td><td><a href="${respuesta.link}">enlace</a></td><td></td></tr>`
                            });
                            $('#licitaciones').html(template);
                        }else{
                            document.getElementById('contendor').innerHTML= '<img src="../resources/defecto.png" class="img-fluid">'; 
                        }
                    },error:function () {
                        console.log('Query no Funciona');
                    }
                });
                break;
};    
};
```

y este es el código que donde se envía la información

```
<?php
include('conexion.php');
session_start();

require ('conexion.php');

switch ($nombre =$_SESSION['nombre']){
    case 'Bianca Albert':
        $consulta = "SELECT id, nombre, ofertante, estado, ejecutor,limite, link FROM licitaciones Where estado='Pendiente' or estado ='En Estudio'";
        $datos = mysqli_query($CRM, $consulta);
        if (!$datos) {
            die('Query Failed'. mysqli_error($base));
        }else{
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($datos)) {
            $json[] = array(
                'id'=> $row['id'],
                'nombre'=> $row['nombre'],
                'ofertante' => $row['ofertante'],
                'estado'=> $row['estado'],
                'ejecutor'=> $row['ejecutor'],
                'limite' => $row['limite'],
                'link' => $row['link']
            );
        };
        }
         $jsonString =json_encode($json);
         echo $jsonString;
    break;
 };
?>
```

Comment: Nunca estás devolviendo un `<br />` así que imagino que el problema real es que *algo* está dando error, y la página de error se está mostrando en HTML, mientras que tú estás intentando leerla como json en JS. Lo correcto aquí no es controlar el error de JS, si no asegurarte de que en la parte de php SIEMPRE devuelves json, y no los mezclas. Una rest API debería ser consistente con sus respuestas, si no empiezas a hacer chapuzas como mirar si la respuesta tiene html o es json. Arregla tu API, te ahorrará dolores de cabeza.

Comment: el código de mi base de datos devuelve un String de una array que son los datos de una consulta en MYSQL, luego ese string que contiene algo como esto **[{…}]
0
: 
{id: '2', nombre: 'Reforma vestuarios Diputación de Almería', ofertante: 'Diputación de Almería', estado: 'Pendiente', ejecutor: 'sin ejecutor', …}
length
: 
1
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)**
y JSON.parse me lo transforma en un objeto

Comment: Yo creo que con añadir la parte del código `$jsonString =json_encode($json); echo $jsonString;` dentro de una declaración `try {} catch` te debería de ser suficiente para poder gestionar tu error, pero como bien cita Benito, lo más adecuado sería solucionar el problema de raíz (arreglar lo que te devuelve la API) y no hacer cosas *algo chapuceras*, como has comentado en la pregunta.

Comment: ya esta solucionado, no era necesario eso solo tuve que revisar el php de donde saco los datos y modificar unas cosas, en cuanto a lo de chapuzas lo digo por como pido los datos, ya que si os dais cuenta entre el código  del js y el codigo del php parece que repito código

Answer (score 0):

el problema es que tu variable $json solo existe dentro del while, por eso al no haber resultados para tu consulta estas enviando una variable que no existe. Define la variable $json como un array vacio antes de ingresar al while, esto solucionará tu problema:

```
$json = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($datos)) {
...
```

Comment: No, ese no era el problema, el problema es que cuando el php envía el resultado lo envia como un string, es decir que todo el array con json_encode se transformaba en una cadena de texto y luego en JS se vuelve a convertir, esta vez en un objeto o objetos, entonces cuando no encontraba nada en la base de datos trataba de crear un objeto y JQUERY le decia que no